# Newline in Ember handlebars helper?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am still a little fuzzy on how to use this helper in my particular situation. I am pulling a random object out of an array of objects and displaying them on button click. Each object has 3 props: word, language, trans. When the object is rendered I would really like it to display as follows

**Word**
langauge 
translation

I have it centered when it renders but all in one line. Here is the code for my helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('randomize', function(myArray, options) {
  var random = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  return random.word + random.language + random.trans;
});
```

So my dumb question is how to I include a line break when it renders?

Comment: This shouldn't go in a helper you should put this in your controller.

Comment: can you put in the chars \r\n somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better tool for the job would be a component. Components automatically come with a template for doing exactly what you want to do, and then your display logic is separate from your business logic.

```
App.RandomWordComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  word: null,
  language: null,
  translation: null,
  createRandomWord: function() {
    this.set('word', Math.random());
    this.set('language', Math.random());
    this.set('translation', Math.random());
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

and the template:

```
<p style="font-weight: bold">
  Word: {{word}}
</p>
<p>
  language: {{language}}
</p>
<p>
  translation: {{translation}}
</p>
```

then use it in your other templates:

```
{{random-word}}
```

I simplified it a bit so you'll need to adjust it to your needs, but hopefully this points you in the right direction. [complete example here](http://jsbin.com/torulo/2/edit)